# factorial using increement for loop gives garbage value

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int fact;
  for(int i=1; i<=fact; i++)
  {
     fact = fact*i;
  }
  cout<<fact;
}
```

Output : garbage value.

Please anyone tell me why using increment for loop gives me this but not decrement for loop.

Comment: `fact` isnt initialized which means its value is indeterminate.

Comment: What is the initial value of `fact`?

Comment: And when you fix that problem, think about using an ever increasing variable as the limit in your loop.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. `fact` has not been initialized.

Answer (score 3):

You can do two things,

1) If you want your own code you must initialize yout value fact with value 1:

```
int fact = 1;
```

2) There is a very simple one liner for this "fact"-stuff. I often use it myself if I need it at some point.

```
int factorial(int n)
{
  return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : factorial(n - 1) * n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
      int fact,z=1;
      cin>>fact;
      for(int i=2; i<=fact; i++)
      {
         z= z*i; //use another variable using fact here will lead to a possible infinite loop
      }
      cout<<z<<"\n";
}
```